# Multivariable assignments across multiple lines in Python

Tags: python, syntax, google-colaboratory

I have a function in my code that returns 6 values. I am trying to assign that to 6 variables using the following code.

```
epitaph_sequence_tokens, epitaph_tokenizer, epitaph_vocab_size, epitaph_padded_sequences, epitaph_X, epitaph_y, epitaph_sequence_length = prep_data(ep_data)
```

All I want to do is split this into two lines, which I figured would be simple by just pressing enter after one of the commas. When I do this I get an unexpected indent error, but if I do not indent it doesn't read it as the same block of code. I am using Google CoLab to code this, is it some issue with that environment that is causing this?

Comment: Please show the code that causes the error.

Comment: Have you considered creating a class to represent these return values? You could then create a single instance of that class and return it rather than returning 6 separate values.

Comment: Using a class is a much better idea haha. Especially since I do this to a few different datasets. Thanks! @Code-Apprentice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parentheses to enable implicit line continuation:

```
(epitaph_sequence_tokens,
 epitaph_tokenizer,
 epitaph_vocab_size,
 epitaph_padded_sequences,
 epitaph_X,
 epitaph_y,
 epitaph_sequence_length) = prep_data(ep_data)
```

(rejoin where you like for only two lines).

Without the parentheses, you need explicitly line continuations using a backslash.

```
epitaph_sequence_tokens, \
epitaph_tokenizer, \
epitaph_vocab_size, \
epitaph_padded_sequences, \
epitaph_X, \
epitaph_y, \
epitaph_sequence_length = prep_data(ep_data)
```

Otherwise, something like

```
epitaph_sequence_tokens,
epitaph_tokenizer,
epitaph_vocab_size,
epitaph_padded_sequences,
epitaph_X,
epitaph_y,
epitaph_sequence_length = prep_data(ep_data)
```

is treated as 6 expression statements (each consisting of a single 1-tuple) followed by one assignment statement. Each of the expression statements requires the name to already be defined in order to create the indicated tuple.